# Extraer de una lista los números primos y guardarlos en una vacía - Python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Código:

```
lista = [3, 11, 6, 10, 97, 31, 2, 6, 14, 16, 17, 21, 199]

primos = []

for i in lista:
    
   cant_div = 0

       for k in lista:

           if(i % k == 0):

               cant_div += 1

       if(cant_div == 2):

           primos.append(i)


print(primos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estas haciendo es comprobar si un numero de `lista` es divisible 2 veces con alguno de los números de `lista`.

Tu resultado es [10, 14, 16, 21] porque:

```
10 es divisible con el mismo y 2  
14 es divisible con el mismo y 2 
16 es divisible con el mismo y 2 
21 es divisible con el mismo y 3
```

## Solución

Para encontrar un número primo solo tienes que hacer 2 comprobaciones:

1. El número tiene que divisible con 1 (Esto es verdadero por defecto)
2. El número solo tiene que ser divisible por el mismo. Para que esto sea verdadero , el número no tiene que ser divisible por ninguno de los números inferiores a el.

```py
lista = [3, 11, 6, 10, 97, 31, 2, 6, 14, 16, 17, 21, 199]

primos = []

def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False        
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

for i in lista: 
    if isPrime(i):
        primos.append(i)
print(primos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reespondiendo a tu pregunta, lo que haces mal en el código es la comprobación de los divisores, para un número `n` estás comparando contra la misma lista de números a comprobar, en lugar de contra `1, 2, 3, ... ,n`

Reemplaza la línea

```
for k in lista:
```

por

```
for k in range(1, i+1):
```

Ya que k debería ser la iteración de los posibles números desde 1 hasta i (la función range no considera el último, por eso le hemos sumado 1)